# Can't Get PHP to tell MYSQL to block user

Tags: php, mysql, connection, installation

i Have a Script for my shop for a game where after they buy something they cant buy anything for 1 week. but i cannot get this script to work. Can Someone Explain to me How to Set up The MySql Database to block the user?

```
<?php
// Purge records
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ip_table WHERE access_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 168 HOUR)");

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM ip_table WHERE ip = '$ip'");
if($result){
  die("TOS: You cannot access this for 1 Week, Security Measure");
} 
else {
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip_table (ip, access_date) VALUES ('$ip', NOW())");
  echo "Thank you For your Purchase. you Have been Blocked For 1 Week due to a Security Measure.";
}
?>
```

All help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: so what output you are getting?? if one or else one??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't check with `if ($result)`, as that will return a valid result resource, even if it has no rows. Therefore, it will always enter the `die()` block.

Instead check `mysql_num_rows()` to see if a row was returned from this query, in addition to testing for `FALSE` in `$result`, which indicates an error in the query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM ip_table WHERE ip = '$ip'");
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
  die("TOS: You cannot access this for 1 Week, Security Measure");
}
```

Note:

Though it should not be possible to launch a SQL injection attack from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS']`, get in the habit of escaping the values in `$_SERVER` anyway:

```
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Update

If you haven't yet figured out how to create this table, here's the statement which will do it:

```
CREATE TABLE ip_table (
  ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  access_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

One issue to consider: Multiple users can appear to your web server as coming from the same originating IP, if they are behind a NAT, a corporate or a school network. You are advised to add some other identifier to the user if you can.

#### Basic MySQL connection pattern:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "someusername", "thepassword");
if (!$conn) {
  // Error connecting.
}
else {
  mysql_select_db("yourDatabaseName");
}
// Now you can call mysql_query()...
```

Comment: Thanks. but Do i select a database?

Comment: @Elycin See addition above. You need to spend some time with the MySQL documentation on php.net http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php. Many examples to get started.

Comment: i used the MySql Console and did that command. No luck at all creating the Table

Comment: Well, what happened? Surely if it didn't work the MySQL console gave you an error message.

Comment: 1067 - Invalid default value for 'access_date' was the Return.

Comment: @Elycin Change the type from `DATETIME` to `TIMESTAMP`. Apparently `DATETIME` can't have a default value.

Comment: @Elycin That just looks like the previous error message got included as part of the SQL statement, probably due to a copy/paste error. Start again with `CREATE TABLE ip_table (ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, access_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );`

Answer (score 0):

try [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
<?php
// Purge records
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ip_table WHERE access_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 168 HOUR)");

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM ip_table WHERE ip = '$ip'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1){
  die("TOS: You cannot access this for 1 Week, Security Measure");
} 
else {
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip_table (ip, access_date) VALUES ('$ip', NOW())");
  echo "Thank you For your Purchase. you Have been Blocked For 1 Week due to a Security Measure.";
}
?>
```

Comment: i like have no clue how to set up the database. that's kinda what i am aiming for. but thanks.